# Content-Policy xpcom component for standalone XULRunner SDK app in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sdk, xpcom, policy, xulrunner

I've created a small browser with `XULRunner SDK 15` and all basic functions work now (`back`, `forward`, `refresh` etc.). I would like to add image blocking capabilities using the `nsIContentPolicy` interface and `shouldLoad` function in Javascript.

I've read all the articles related to this here and all Mozilla sites; And I've looked into the source of `AdBlock`, `NoScript`, `ImgLikeOpera` and similar addons using the interface, but nothing I've tried has worked for me; The images are always loaded.

Could anyone help me in creating the component? What other interfaces can I use the block the images before they start to load?

Comment: After modifying every components code that work with Firefox I thought it's hardly likely that there's a problem with the code itself. I looked into the filesystem of the SDK and figured out that the javascript implementation of the nsIContentPolicy interface is missing while in the XULRunner source code the C++ implementation exists. So the question is how could I add the javascript implementation to the SDK (where can it be downloaded from) or how could I recompile the source including this (and maybe all other) interface as well.

Comment: Ok. I was just curious and put my component code into a Firefox extension. It worked perfectly. For the standalone XULRunner app nothing works. Even the simplest "Hello world" does not show the alertbox. Anyone has any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Use the image permissions setting in the XULRunner [prefs.js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/XULRunner/Debugging_XULRunner_applications) to do this:

```
pref("permissions.default.image", 2);
```

**References**

- [permissions.default.image KB Article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Permissions.default.image)
- [How do I turn off image loading](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/961547)
- [How do I block pictures](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/976872)